# Uploading File using Ajax in Asp.Net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Good day everyone,

I'm trying to upload file using ajax from client side to server side (asp.net core) controller but I'm having a null value.

Here's my html and javascript codes:

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" class="required" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="uploadcsvfile()">

<script>
    function uploadcsvfile() {
       var myfile= document.getElementById("myfile");
       var formData = new FormData();

       if (myfile.files.length > 0) {
           for (var i = 0; i < myfile.files.length; i++) {
               formData.append('file-' + i, myfile.files[i]);
           }
       }

       $.ajax({
           url: "/MyController/UploadFile/",
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           data: formData,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           success: function(data){

           },
           error: function (data) {

           }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Here's my controller that uses IFormFile

```
public async Task<JsonResult> UploadFile(IFormFile formData)
{
      // do something here
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Whats the issue now? DO you even get a call at your action method at all?

Comment: Is the server expecting `data: {formData:formData}`? What is `formData` expected to be at `public async Task<JsonResult> UploadFile(IFormFile formData)`? What is purpose of `Task<JsonResult>`?

Comment: @guest271314 same if I use that with braces, I get null

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari I'm able to break the method but the value of the formData is null

Comment: Have not tried asp.net, though noticed `JSON` at `Task<JsonResult>` and reference to `formData` apparently expected to reference `formData` at JavaScript? `FormData` `Content-Type` at `POST` request is `multipart/form-data`, not `application/json`

Comment: i think you got confused between myfile.files and excelfile.files

Comment: @Ahefaz I already updated the question

Comment: @jsonGPPD Can you accept an answer please? I've just tried Mohammed Noureldin's answer and that worked for me, which one worked for you?

Answer (score 66):

It is well explained [here](http://sikorsky.pro/en/blog/file-uploading-with-aspnet-core-what-options-do-we-have):

## Browser Side Code:

#### HTML

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="/uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="upload-button">
      <div class="label">Click me!</div>
      <input id="files" name="files" type="file" size="1" multiple onchange="uploadFiles('files');" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function uploadFiles(inputId) {
  var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
  var files = input.files;
  var formData = new FormData();

  for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
    formData.append("files", files[i]);
  }

  $.ajax(
    {
      url: "/uploader",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: "POST",
      success: function (data) {
        alert("Files Uploaded!");
      }
    }
  );
}
```

---

## Server Side Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IList<IFormFile> files)
{
  foreach (IFormFile source in files)
  {
    string filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(source.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

    filename = this.EnsureCorrectFilename(filename);

    using (FileStream output = System.IO.File.Create(this.GetPathAndFilename(filename)))
      await source.CopyToAsync(output);
  }

  return this.View();
}

private string EnsureCorrectFilename(string filename)
{
  if (filename.Contains("\\"))
    filename = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

  return filename;
}

private string GetPathAndFilename(string filename)
{
  return this.hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads\\" + filename;
}
```

Comment: Working Perfectly.

Comment: In my case Model which I am sending contains other information also like firstname last name etc .

public class Model
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public List<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
}

When i send from ajax I am getting 400 status code.   How to post?

Comment: @SagarPatil please post a new question about the problem and add the link to your question as a comment here, and I will be glad to do my best trying to help.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin please find my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/59422872/9491935

Comment: Your creativity in listing the best options.
Very beautiful

Answer (score 23):

Here's a simple way to post a file to your controller's action.

**View**:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#myfile')[0].files[0]); // myFile is the input type="file" control

var _url = '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "MyController")';

$.ajax({
    url: _url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success: function (result) {
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
    }
});
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    List<string> errors = new List<string>(); // added this just to return something

    if (file != null)
    {
        // do something
    }

    return Json(errors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
}
```

Comment: how is the content type being set to media?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane AFAIK jquery will automatically set the proper content type for your ajax request. I am currently using this setup for uploading excel documents in one of my projects.

Comment: The thing is, in Asp.Net Core, there's no HttpPostedFileBase but only IFormFile. Is there a way I can achieve the file?

Comment: @jsonGPPD forgot about that. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Fully working example with (.Net Core). Some portion of the answer adopted from the above answers with fixing the compilation errors.

Assuming you want to upload files then you'll submit the form with the uploaded files.

> Register.cshtml

```
@using UploadFileAjaxPostWebApp.Models.Account

@model RegisterModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <div>
    <label>First Name </label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="John" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Second Name </label>
    <input type="text" name="SecondName" value="Smith" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Resume</label>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload1" onchange="uploadFiles('fileUpload1');" />
    <input type="hidden" id="ResumeFileName" name="ResumeFileName" value="@Model.ResumeFileName" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

function uploadFiles(inputId) {
    var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
    var files = input.files;
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i !== files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files", files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/account/uploadfiles",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                // Set the property of the Model.
                $("#ResumeFileName").val(data.fileName);
                alert("Files Uploaded! " + data.fileName);
            }
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

> Account Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using UploadFileAjaxPostWebApp.Models.Account;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace UploadFileAjaxPostWebApp.Controllers
{
  public class AccountController : Controller
  {
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

    public AccountController(IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        // Handle your post action ....
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFiles(IList<IFormFile> files)
    {
        string fileName = null;

        foreach (IFormFile source in files)
        {
            // Get original file name to get the extension from it.
            string orgFileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(source.ContentDisposition).FileName.Value;

            // Create a new file name to avoid existing files on the server with the same names.
            fileName = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + Path.GetExtension(orgFileName);

            string fullPath = GetFullPathOfFile(fileName);

            // Create the directory.
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetParent(fullPath).FullName);

            // Save the file to the server.
            await using FileStream output = System.IO.File.Create(fullPath);
            await source.CopyToAsync(output);
        }

        var response = new { FileName = fileName };

        return Ok(response);
    }

    private string GetFullPathOfFile(string fileName)
    {
        return $"{_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\uploads\\{fileName}";
    }
 }
}
```

> RegisterModel class

```
namespace UploadFileAjaxPostWebApp.Models.Account
{
  public class RegisterModel
  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public string ResumeFileName { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify file input "name" attribute (same as variable name in ASP.NET controller).
HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="thefile" />
```

C#:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile thefile) { }
```

For AJAX request you need to specify appropriate name in FormData object.

Answer (score 0):

#### Getting null value because of different parameter name.

**Client side:**
Instead of setting file-i add fromData ***same*** as your action method paramter name

```
formData.append('formData' myfile.files[i]);
```

---

#### As you are uploading csv file, add validation to allow only csv files.

```
function uploadcsvfile() {
    var myfile= document.getElementById("myfile");
    var formData = new FormData();
    if (myfile.value.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".csv") == -1) 
    {
      alert("Please upload a file with .csv extension.");
      return false;
    } 
    
    // else code to upload
}
```

---

#### As you are upload multiple files

**Html:** add multiple attritube

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" class="required" multiple />
```

**ServerSide:** Add list of [IFromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

```
public async Task<JsonResult> UploadFile(List<IFormFile> formData)
{
      // do something here
}
```

If you not using form tag, then add ***@Html.AntiForgeryToken()***

Answer (score 0):

```js
var GetImages = $('[name="Images"]');
console.log(GetImages[0].files)

for (var i = 0; i != GetImages[0].files.length; i++) {
    form.append("Images", GetImages[0].files[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you also maybe explain how this code solves the problem?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.