# IformFile in the action controller takes the value as null, value is pass to the action controller using ajax request

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, http-post

I am trying to get the value passed from the ajax request into one of the method in the controller  but IFormFile files is null every time. 
Here is my ajax request :

```
 uploadFile: function (field, value) 
{
    var me = this;
    var view = me.getView();
    var fileuploadControl = me.lookupReference('ImportFile');
    var file = fileuploadControl.fileInputEl.el.dom.files[0];   
    var param = new FormData();
    param.append('files', file);
    var ajax = Ext.Ajax.request(
  {

        url: './../XYController/ImportCSVFile',
                data: param,
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                headers: { 'accept': '*/*' },
                processData: true,
                success: function (response, options) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                    if (mask) {
                        mask.destroy();
                    }   
                    Ext.Msg.alert("File Upload Successful");
   }

});
```

},

And this is my Action Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("XYController/ImportCSVFile")]
public IActionResult ImportCSVFile(IFormFile files)
{
  if(files!=null)
   {
    //do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For file upload , The `contenttype` needs to be set to `false` along with the `processData` option. Otherwise jQuery will not see this as a file upload :

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

See code samples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903310/uploading-file-using-ajax-in-asp-net-core) , that should be same no matter use ExtJS or other Jquery wrapper library .