# Send file with ajax to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to store a file in my database, and I am using tabulator and I dont have a form created. So I am using a simple `var editor = document.createElement("input");`, them after clicking the file he triggers a button created in the moment, and sends it throught ajax to a controller but... in controller I get count=0 and In my javascript I have the file.
this is the javasript

```
var imagem_insert = function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel) {
            var editor = document.createElement("input");
            editor.setAttribute("type", "file");
            editor.setAttribute("id", "get_anexo");

            var send = document.createElement("button");
            var row_stamp = cell.getRow().getData().u_listamat;
            let selectedFile
            function successFuncEditor() {
                
                send.click();
                
            }
            editor.addEventListener("change", successFuncEditor);

            function successFuncSend() {
                selectedFile = document.getElementById('get_anexo').files[0];

                console.log(selectedFile);
                const file_name = selectedFile.name;
                const file_size = selectedFile.size;
                const file_type = selectedFile.type;

                let form = new FormData;

                form.append('Image', selectedFile);
                form.append('Name', file_name);
                form.append('size', file_size);
                form.append('tipo', file_type);

                console.log(form.get("Name"));

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    url: "/Lista/Insert",
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: { files: form },
                    success: function (data) { }
                })
            }
            send.addEventListener("click", successFuncSend)

            //return the editor element
            return editor;
        }
```

And this is the controler

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        byte[] arq = null;
        string nome_ficheiro = null;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                arq = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
                nome_ficheiro = file.FileName;
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Try Request.Files & check if you get anything.

Comment: Like this?
foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var test= Request.Files[file];
            }

Comment: Nope. First check the Request.Files.Count > 0, if count == 1 then your file can be found at Request.Files[0] or Request.Files[i] if you're using loop.

Comment: I don't have the file option when I type Request, and If i write it, says  does not contain a definition for 'files' and no accessible extension method 'Files'

Comment: Request.Form.Files.Count I am trying this isn't the same?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Incorrect Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8'

when I tried I got this error, and the count on the List<IFormFile> files is 0 and not null

Comment: Sorry my bad, in Dot Net Core you need to use HttpContext.Request.Form.Files

Comment: same error then before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading File using Ajax in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903310/uploading-file-using-ajax-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Suggest you to change line from "form.append('Image', selectedFile)" to "form.append('files', selectedFile)"

Comment: responding to @Karan yes and no, yes it would work if I had a form but I dont, I just have an input and a button, So if i can create a form with just javascript like using this document.createElement then yes if it doesn't I think It wont answer it but I am going to give it a better look

Comment: Try with removing `datatype: 'json',`. Replace `data: { files: form }` with `data: form`. Create `form` object as `let form = new FormData; form.append('files', selectedFile);`.

Comment: hehehehe got it! Can you try to explain a little the why those changes are needed?

Comment: In `form.append('files', selectedFile);` use `files` as `key` because you have `action parameter name` as `files`. `datatype: 'json'` that is not in this case it could be `multipart/form-data`. Or if you search other related questions no one is using it. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1 to know how posted values are bind to action parameters.

Comment: hummmm I see tahnk mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to respond and to be more clear to find the anwser and base on @kane and @Mohan Rajput, and by the way thanks for the time to respond, I ended up with this.

javascript

```
var imagem_insert = function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel) {
            var editor = document.createElement("input");
            editor.setAttribute("type", "file");
            editor.setAttribute("id", "get_anexo");
            editor.setAttribute("name", "files");

            var send = document.createElement("button");
            var row_stamp = cell.getRow().getData().u_listamat;
            let selectedFile
            function successFuncEditor() {
                
                send.click();
                
            }
            editor.addEventListener("change", successFuncEditor);

            function successFuncSend() {
                selectedFile = document.getElementById('get_anexo').files[0];

                let form = new FormData;
                form.append('files', selectedFile);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    url: "/Lista/Insert",
                    data: form ,
                    success: function (data) { }
                })
            }
            send.addEventListener("click", successFuncSend)

            //return the editor element
            return editor;
        }
```

so instead fo tryning to send file_name, type and size to the controller one by one, I changed it to send all together.
So my controller is something Like this.

```
public ActionResult Insert(IFormFile files)
    {
        byte[] arq = null;
        string nome_ficheiro = null;
        string type = null;

        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(files.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            arq = reader.ReadBytes((int)files.Length);
            type = files.ContentType;
            nome_ficheiro = files.FileName;
        }
        var send_img = PhcWeb.Lista.send_image_db(arq,type,nome_ficheiro);
        return View();
    }
```

**NOTE:** if you want to send more then one, you need to use `List<IFormFile>`