# Uploading image file with ajax and receiving it with in the asp.net core mvc controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have tried all possible ways mentioned in this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903310/uploading-file-using-ajax-in-asp-net-core/49966788), however didn't have any progress. Please help.

So my ajax request is as below:

```
function photoUploadConfirmed() {
            event.preventDefault();
            var files = $("#image")[0].files;
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", files[0]);
            console.log(files); // I just check here and in browser I can see file name and size
            console.log(formData); // I expect to see the same here, but here it almost shows empty
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Account/ChangeProfilePicture",
                data: { image: formData }, // In the controller it receives IFormFile image
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function () {
                    console.log("Done");
                    $("#profilePhoto").val('');
                    $("#profPicUploadConfirm").attr("disabled", true);
                },
                error: function (errorMessage) {
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                }
            });
        }
```

The ajax post request gets received by the controller's action, however the IFormFile image is always null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeProfilePicture(IFormFile image)
    {
       // I do save here the image in the folder, but problem is that image==null
    }
```

Comment: your file name should match with the input parameter name, change image to file. And use [FromBody] attribute with the input param

Comment: @MuhammadKamranAslam I tried this one also, still no happy end result

Comment: can you share a sample for this code,

Comment: @MuhammadKamranAslam the solution is posted below, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The ajax post request gets received by the controller's action,
> however the IFormFile image is always null.

When the file is uploaded by formData append, the name at this time should be the same as `"image"` of the receiving parameter in action:

```
formData.append("image", files[0]);
```

And because you only need to pass the IFormFile to the action, in the **data** parameter of `ajax`, **you only need to put the formData which appends the file named Image to it**:

```
 data: formData,
```

Change your js as follow:

```
function photoUploadConfirmed() {
            event.preventDefault();
            var files = $("#image")[0].files;
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image", files[0]);
            console.log(files); // I just check here and in browser I can see file name and size
            console.log(formData); // I expect to see the same here, but here it almost shows empty
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Account/ChangeProfilePicture",
                data: formData, // In the controller it receives IFormFile image
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function () {
                    console.log("Done");
                    $("#profilePhoto").val('');
                    $("#profPicUploadConfirm").attr("disabled", true);
                },
                error: function (errorMessage) {
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and even after updating the changes as suggested in previous answer, it didn't work for me.
Finally found the solution :

```
formData.append("fileInfo", fileInfo, "uploadedfile"); // uploadedfile is file name which at compile time converts to FormFile in Action method
```